# Xcodegen cache works wrong or i mistake

Tags: swift, xcodegen

I have a git hook post-checkout, when i checkout i start a script it's just a one line - "xcodegen generate --use-cache".
So the bug is that it's not work in my case.
My case:
Everything happens in local repo.
I create new branch from develop for example branch-1.
I create a new file on branch-1 with some swift class, commit it in local repo and then go back to develop.
When i checkout hook start a command - "xcodegen generate --use-cache" but it says "Project ProjectName has not changed since cache was written", but develop doesn't has a new file which i created on branch-1.
For this case i need to write xcodegen generate on terminal by hand.
Whats wrong why it doesn't work and how can i fix it?

If i use xcodegen generate without --use-cache it works fine.